# Paperclip #reprocess! method is not creating thumbnails (Ruby 1.9.2 & Rails 3 )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using

Ruby 1.9.2,
Rails 3.0.1
Paperclip 2.3.4

When I go into my console and type

```
irb(main):001:0> Listing.find(111).photo_1.reprocess!
=> true
```

it return true. But when I go inot `public/system/photo_1s/111/`
I have only `original/` directory with the original pic. I have no other directories like `thumbnail/` or `medium/` those for which I have created styles in my model file as below

```
has_attached_file :photo_1, :styles => { :medium => "260x195>", :thumbnail => '64x64#'}
```

what could have gone wrong. Is this an issue with paperclip ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a before_image_post_process filter in your Listing class which is returning false. This causes reprocess! to not actually do any of the processing, but the method will still return true.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command in the rails console not irb

`./script/console`   in Rails <3

or

`rails c`  in Rails 3

Comment: I've just tried what you are wanting to do on a test application and its working fine, so I can only offer up the following advice :
Check that your model name is the same as the directory you are looking in eg you had photo_1 as the model and photo_1s as the directory.
Also, check that you haven't configured paperclip to save the processed images in another folder.